# How to show cursor on TextInput using forwardTo in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have two elements on screen, one Rectangle and one TextInput.When the activefocus is set on the rectangle and I type anything, I need to get the typed input to the TextInput

For this, I have used `curRect.Keys.forwardTo = [curTextbox];`

It works properly, but i also want to see the cursor while the focus is on the rectangle.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-textinput.html#cursorVisible-prop

In the above link by QT, it says

> that It can be set directly in script, for example if a KeyProxy
>   might forward keys to it and you desire it to look active when this
>   happens (but without actually giving it active focus).

But that does not happen in my case.

Can anyone explain to me why that is and how I can achieve my goal, i.e. to show the cursor even when the *activeFocus* is on the Rectangle?

Even if the cursor is shown at the time of entering the text it would be great.

**UPDATE:**

```
import QtQuick 1.0

FocusScope{

    width: 400
    height: 400
    TextInput {Rectangle{anchors.fill: parent;color:"#66ff0000"}
        id: mytext
        anchors.top:parent.top
        cursorVisible: true
        width: rect.width
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: mytext.forceActiveFocus()
        }
        Keys.onDownPressed: {
            mytext2.forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }
    TextInput {Rectangle{anchors.fill: parent;color:"#66ff0000"}
        id: mytext2
        anchors.top:mytext.bottom
        cursorVisible: true
        width: rect.width
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: mytext2.forceActiveFocus()
        }

        Keys.onUpPressed: {
            mytext.forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id:rect
        width: 360
        height: 360
        color:rect.activeFocus?"#6600ff00":"#660000ff"
        focus: true
        Keys.forwardTo: mytext
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: rect.forceActiveFocus()
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: rect.forceActiveFocus();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not possible. You can always enter | sign on blur so there will be something inside the input. But it will not blink. And on focus you can move the cursor back to the position where pipe was and delete it.

Comment: @JakubPolomský are you sure? The documentation seems to indicate it is. I never tried this, though.

Comment: I think it might be easier to just transfer the active focus to the TextInput, why is that no option for you?

Comment: How are you trying to do this? I could get it to work in the most straightforward way possible. See my answer for the code. Provide code so that we can help you better.

Comment: Hi, Please see my sample code that I added

Comment: It should work something like when the last active focus was on textbox 2 and then the current active focus is on rectangle, the rectangle should still key forward to text box 1, but the cursor will not still display

Comment: @rkc88 you should tag users with `@username` if you want them to see your comments (except if you're commenting their own post)... the site hasn't sent me a message that you posted a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of focus resets the `cursorVisible` property... so, when you click `rect`, and the focus is transferred from `mytext` to it via `forceActiveRecord`, `mytext.cursorVisible` is automatically set to false. You should reset it to true if you want to keep the cursor visible. This can be done by changing your `rect.MouseArea.onClicked` to this:

```
        onClicked: {
            rect.forceActiveFocus();
            mytext.cursorVisible = true;
        }
```

If you want the cursor on `mytext` to be always visible, you can also use the `onCursorVisibleChanged` handler to force it to be true. Use this inside your `mytext` object:

```
    onCursorVisibleChanged: {
        if (!cursorVisible)
            cursorVisible = true;
    }
```

PS: I'm posting a new answer, since added details have changed it a lot... I might delete the previous one later.